# Go tries to handle an error instead of me

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following code running using GORM:

```
result := db.Where("account_name = ?", config.AccountName).First(&accountRecord) // line 299

    // if there is some error when working with DB
    if result.Error != nil && !errors.Is(result.Error, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
        fmt.Println("error when processing accountResponse")
        return 0, false, result.Error
    }

// in case that record exists
    if result.Error != nil {
        accountRecord = newAcountData

        result = db.Create(&accountRecord)
    } else {
        result = db.Model(&accountRecord).Updates(newAcountData)
    }
```

I already do want to run some logic in the case where the record was not found. However - the error is still shown in my console saying `The record was not found`:

```
2021/08/30 18:30:16 /Users/kana/projects/server/data-processor/commands.go:289 record not found
[4.966ms] [rows:0] SELECT * FROM "accounts" WHERE account_name = 'kana' AND "accounts"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "accounts"."id" LIMIT 1
```

Why does that happen? The whole program runs fine after that - nothing crashes and the overall behavior is the way it was designed. Simply this error message annoys me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the GORM is handling some log outputs and `record not found` is one of them. If you need to disable these kind of log activities you can do the followings:

if you are using GORM v1

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.LogMode

```golang
db.LogMode(false)
```

if you are using GORM v2 you can pass logger to gorm config and control the outputs.

https://gorm.io/docs/logger.html#Log-Levels

```golang
db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{
  Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Silent),
})
```